# Macro declaration giving errors

Tags: c, macros, compiler-errors

I declare macros which would make it easy to replicate the logic of writing to a file Log
I end up getting the error C2065: 'flog' : undeclared identifier. 
But I don't get this error for log_buffer.

I am using Visual Studios 2008 IDE.

What am i doing wrong?

```
#ifndef ERROR_LOG_MACRO

#define ERROR_LOG_MACRO 1

#define SETERRORPARAMS  char log_buffer[MAX_PATH]; \
                        char flog[MAX_PATH]; \
                        FILE *err_log_fp; 

/*
    Arguments: x (Name of the File) 
               y (File Path without the Filename)
               z (Mode) 
*/                  
#define OPENFILE(x,y,z) strcpy(flog,y); \
                        strcat(flog,"\\"); \
                        strcat(flog,x); \ 
                        err_log_fp = fopen(flog, z); 

#define WRITELOG(x)     if(err_log_fp) \
                            fwrite(log_buffer, sizeof(char), strlen(log_buffer), err_log_fp);

#define CLOSEFILE       if(err_log_fp) \
                            fclose(err_log_fp);

#endif
```

I even tried to do

```
#define OPENFILE(x,y,z)   SETERRORPARAMS \ 
                          ... \
```

But even this did not work.

Comment: can you show the function that it fails in?

Comment: Why are you using macros for this ? Why not implement this properly, with functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have trailing whitespaces after the first line of your macro:

```
#define SETERRORPARAMS  char log_buffer[MAX_PATH]; \______ <-- make sure you have no whitespaces
                    char flog[MAX_PATH]; \
                    FILE *err_log_fp;
```

Either that, or you're not using the macro and `log_buffer` is declared elsewhere.

Comment: The White Spaces were causing the issue :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually *checked* that `flog` is in scope wherever you're using the `OPENFILE` macro?

Such as with the code segment:

```
SETERRORPARAMS
OPENFILE (fileStr, pathStr, modeStr)
```

Worst case, you'll have to examine the code after the preprocessor has done its work. Most compilers will let you examine the output produced by that preprocessor stage. GCC would use `gcc -E` but I'm not sure what the equivalent is to MSVC.

[This link](http://weseetips.com/2008/06/12/how-to-get-the-preprocessed-c-cpp-source-files/) seems to indicate you can enter `/P` into the project settings to get the preprocoessed files written to `*.i` files.

But, I've got to say this, using macros for this is not really a good idea. In the old days, it used to be good for speed purposes but it's not really necessary in these days of inline functions and very good code optimisers.

Comment: Ok. I will try to implement what you suggested for sure. Thanks :)